# Any (PHP) code editors for ARM Linux?

Tags: linux, php, editor, arm

I have a quick question. I want to start using my Chromebook more, and since Linux apps are available I was wondering if there is a (PHP) code editor with FTP support for ARM Linux on Chromebooks.

This would be really helpful. Especially with the ftp support.

Comment: What have you found yourself? Many editors that work on x86 should also work on ARM.

Comment: I tried editors like Netbeans, CudaText, Bluefish and a few more.. The Netbeans editor worked, but I didn't have php and ftp support. After that I tried a php version of Netbeans but that one could only be installed on x64 and x86. Also installing plugins in Netbeans gave errors. If there is a php version of Netbeans with ftp support for ARM than I would be happy :)